# Create 4 dimensions Array with response of Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax, object

i have these array in javascript:

```
var data = [
          { y: '2017-01', a: 50,  b: 90, c:110},
          { y: '2017-02', a: 65,  b: 75, c:120},
          { y: '2017-03', a: 50,  b: 50, c:10},
          { y: '2017-04', a: 75,  b: 60, c:170},
          { y: '2017-05', a: 80,  b: 65, c:60},
          { y: '2017-06', a: 90,  b: 70, c:30},
          { y: '2017-07', a: 100, b: 75, c:10},
          { y: '2017-08', a: 115, b: 75, c:0},
          { y: '2017-09', a: 120, b: 85, c:0}
        ]
```

I created that ajax call that gives back a JSON.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "php/get_incomes_months.php",
                data: {year:current_year},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {  
                    var data_array = [
                        {y:data[0]['date'], a:data[0]['validated'], b:data[0]['revenue'], c:data[0]['costes']},
                        {y:data[1]['date'], a:data[1]['validated'], b:data[1]['revenue'], c:data[1]['costes']}
                    ];
                    fooDone(data_array); //after we have data, we pass it to fooDone    
                },
                error: function(data){

                }
            });
```

This is the JSON:

```
0   Object
validated   "0"
revenue "50244.81"
costes  "0"
date    "2017-01"
1   Object
validated   "44788.16"
revenue "30640.51"
costes  "0"
date    "2017-02"
2   Object
validated   "68324.64"
revenue "80363.51"
costes  "11072.73"
date    "2017-03"
3   Object
validated   "0"
revenue "50244.81"
costes  "0"
date    "2017-04"
4   Object
validated   "2738"
revenue "103145.62"
costes  "11"
date    "2017-05"
5   Object
validated   "510"
revenue "1459283.09"
costes  "213"
date    "2017-06"
6   Object
validated   "24034.21"
revenue "50367.81"
costes  "0"
date    "2017-07"
7   Object
validated   "24"
revenue "50244.81"
costes  "0"
date    "2017-08"
```

here in the success function i have to create inside a FOR bucle the array, actually i'm doing it manually....

```
success: function(data) {  
                        var data_array = [
                            {y:data[0]['date'], a:data[0]['validated'], b:data[0]['revenue'], c:data[0]['costes']},
                            {y:data[1]['date'], a:data[1]['validated'], b:data[1]['revenue'], c:data[1]['costes']}
                        ];
```

please help

Comment: Just loop through all json objects and push them into your data array with data_array.push(your_object)

Comment: can you specifi more please? @NeuTronas

Comment: @SergioSuarez Take a look at the first alternative of my answer. This is what he's talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your actual code you are always returning an array of two elements, this won't give you the desired results.

You should declare an empty array and push the custom object to it in each iteration.

```
success: function(data) {
  var data_array = [];
  data.forEach(function(obj) {
    data_array.push({
      y: obj['date'],
      a: obj['validated'],
      b: obj['revenue'],
      c: obj['costes']
    });
  });
  fooDone(data_array);
},
```

You can just use `.map()` method to create your custom array from your `data` array, this is how should be your code:

```
success: function(data) {
  var data_array = data.map(function(obj) {
    return {
      y: obj['date'],
      a: obj['validated'],
      b: obj['revenue'],
      c: obj['costes']
    };
  });
  fooDone(data_array);
},
```

For each `object` of your `data` array it will return a custom `object` with the requested properties.

Comment: @SergioSuarez Great, glad it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.prototype.map` to create a new array from a function of the `data` array.

```js
var data = [
  { date: '2017-01', validated: 50,  revenue: 90, costes:110},
  { date: '2017-02', validated: 65,  revenue: 75, costes:120},
  { date: '2017-03', validated: 50,  revenue: 50, costes:10},
  { date: '2017-04', validated: 75,  revenue: 60, costes:170},
  { date: '2017-05', validated: 80,  revenue: 65, costes:60},
  { date: '2017-06', validated: 90,  revenue: 70, costes:30},
  { date: '2017-07', validated: 100, revenue: 75, costes:10},
  { date: '2017-08', validated: 115, revenue: 75, costes:0},
  { date: '2017-09', validated: 120, revenue: 85, costes:0}
];
var data_array = data.map(e => ({y: e.date, a: e.validated, b: e.revenue, c: e.costes}));
console.log(data_array);
```

Comment: @Barman SyntaxError: missing ; before statement[Saber más]  i was given that error.

Comment: Added parentheses to fix the syntax ambiguity in arrow functions.